# Converting tensorflow dataset to numpy array

Tags: tensorflow

I have an autoencoder defined using `tf.keras` in tensorflow 1.15. I cannot upgrade to tensorflow to 2.0 for some specific reasons.

This particular autoencoder is used for anomaly detection. I currently compute the AUC score of the autoencoder as follows:

1. All anomalous inputs are labelled 1 and all normal inputs are labelled 0. This is `y_true`
2. I feed the autoencoder with unseen inputs and then measure the reconstruction error, like so: `errors = np.mean(np.square(data - model.predict(data)), axis=-1)`
3. The mean of this array is then said to the predicted label, `y_pred`.
4. I then compute the AUC using `auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)`.

This approach works well. I now need to move towards using `tf.data.dataset` to feed in my data. Previously, it was numpy arrays. The issue is, I am unable to convert tf.data.dataset to a numpy array and hence unable to compute the mean squared error as seen in 2.

Once I have a `tf.data.Dataset`, I feed it for prediction like so: `results = model.predict(x_test)`

This yields a numpy array, `results`. I want to compute the mean square error of `results` with `x_test`. However, `x_test` is of type `tf.data.Dataset`. So the question is, how can I convert a tf.data.dataset to a numpy array in tensorflow 1.15 or what is an alternative method to do this?

Comment: It is unclear why you need to convert your data to a numpy array just to compute the MSE.

Comment: @gobrewers14 updated with more detail.

Comment: Yes ,tf.data.Dataset can be converted to iterable numpy arrays. Please look at this link.                            https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/as_numpy